# complex hide and show with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

The main idea is to make the element appear on click and hide it on any mouse click event.
I have the following html code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="name">Author 1</span>
    <span class="affiliation">Institution 1</span> 
  </li>
<li>
    <span class="name">Author 2</span>
    <span class="affiliation">Institution 2</span> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I exactly want is to show next span.affiliation after clicking on span.name. Hide it on every other click (on any html element), but if the users clicks on other span.name - additionally show next span.affiliation. I have already tried several variants without success.

Example of the javascript, that I have already tried:

```
  $('span.affiliation').hide();
  $('span.name').click(function() { 
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks'); 
  var target = $(this).next('span.affiliation'); 
  if (clicks) { 
    target.hide(); 
  } else { 
    $('span.affiliation').not(target).hide(); 
    var pos = $(this).position(); 
    var width = $(this).outerWidth(); 
    $(this).next(target).css({ 
      position: "absolute", 
      top: pos.top + 30 + "px", 
      left: pos.left + (-5) + "px" 
    }).delay(80).show('slow'); 
  } 
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks); 
});
```

Comment: Use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: simple .toggle() will not do the trick

Comment: Not entirely certain about logic. Which elements are initially not displayed? `.affiliation` elements? Can you include `css` and `javascript` which you have tried to solve issue at Question?

Comment: Yep. span with class "affiliation" initially are hidden. Simple toggle makes affiliation appear by clicking on span with class name. It is fairly easy. But the idea is to show element on first click on "name" and hide on any mouse click event.

Comment: Hide `.affiliation` elements on any click? Or hide `.affiliation` elements on every other click?

Comment: Have added the code snippet. But I am thinking that it is a wrong way...

Comment: Sorry for my English. First off all I want to show an element by clicking on other element, but hide it on next click on any html element. Other part of code I think that can write by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var $affiliations = $('.affiliation');
  
  $(document.body).on('click', function(e){
    var $clickedElement = $(e.target);
    
    if ($clickedElement.is('.name')) {
      $affiliations.not($clickedElement.next('.affiliation')).hide();
      $clickedElement.next('.affiliation').toggle();
    } else {
      $affiliations.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.affiliation { display: none; }

body {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="name">Author 1</span>
    <span class="affiliation">Institution 1</span> 
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="name">Author 2</span>
    <span class="affiliation">Institution 2</span> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is exactly what I meant :)